# Django can send "reset password" mail but cannot use the "send_mail"

Tags: python, django, email

I want to send a "greetings" mail, when people sign up for my webpage.

I can send a "reset password" email using the built in `auth_views.PasswordResetView` but when I try use the `django.core.mail.send_mail` I get an `Username and Password not accepted.`

My `settings.py`

```py
.
.
#Email config
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "My Name <no-reply@my_site.com>"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = app_cred
EMAIL_HOST_USER = app_email
```

and `views.py`

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST": #post request
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        agree_form = AgreeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and agree_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            user.save()
            
            send_mail(subject = "Welcome to my-site.com",
            message = "Welcome!",
            from_email = None,
            recipient_list = [user.email])
            return redirect("login")
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        agree_form = AgreeForm()

    return render(request,"users/register.html",context= {"form":form,"agree_form":agree_form})
```

As far as I understand, Django uses the credentials specified in the settings, so I wonder why I can send a password-reset mail but cannot use the `send_mail` method using the same credentials?

Comment: Any logs? Are you sure you go into `if form.is_valid() and agree_form.is_valid():`?

Comment: Yes, tha'd been working for a while. I have just added the "send_mail" since I want to add that

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to SO, and I don't have the reputation to comment this, otherwise I would, but I think it's because if no value is provided for the 'from_email' parameter in 'send_mail' then it defaults to the 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL' value provided in the settings, in your case 'My Name <no-reply@my_site.com>'. If that is the case then my assumption would be that it is trying to authenticate you on the Gmail servers with that email (My Name <no-reply@my_site.com>), and whatever your password is. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/).

A quick way to check this would be to change the 'from_email' value in 'send_email' from None to 'EMAIL_HOST_USER',

```
send_mail(subject = "Welcome to my-site.com",
        message = "Welcome!",
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        recipient_list = [user.email])
        return redirect("login")
```

or to change your 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL' value to the same as your 'EMAIL_HOST_USER' value.

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = app_email
EMAIL_HOST_USER = app_email
```

I'm not too sure what your backend looks like with regards to sending emails, but I hope this helps!

Comment: What happend was, that I had recently changed my password, and for some reason, that removed my app-passwords in gmail i.e the credentials was simply just wrong

Answer (score 0):

What happend was, that I had recently changed my password to the gmail-account, and for some reason, that removed my app-passwords in the gmail i.e the credentials was simply wrong